# Modular web application using play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am attempting to write a web app shell that will incooporate other applications (report, traffic, admin).

I intend to have the apps as separate war files all runing within jboss.
The shell application will handle login in to the other applications.
Different users will have access to different modules.

I hope to use play framework for the back end.

Is the play framework able to produce such a modular design?

Are the templates for such a thing? If I could be pointed in teh right direction to get this started id greatly appreciate.

Comment: Play supports the modularization of the app, but it does not support war out of the box. You can try https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin, but I don't know how well it would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use JBoss then Play is wrong path.

JBoss is a complete Java EE implementation, which acts as a container for application packaged as *.war or *.ear. Java EE depends on servlets.

Play uses SBT build tool which produces a complete package with web server (Netty) containing your web application. Play applications don't use servlets at all. (Technically, you can emulate then by using aforementioned war plugin, but that's not recommended). Application and its modules are contained in separate *.jar files.

So the answer is: Yes, you can have modular architecture in Play, but not the way you would like to. Play stays away from the Java EE burden. You can force it to act as a Java EE compatible web app, but it would be totally against framework design.

If I could make an advice - take a look at Spring MVC, it may suit your needs better.